# What is a counterexample to the converse of the Absolute Value Theorem for sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series

So I just recently learned this about explicit sequences:

$\displaystyle\text{If }\lim_{n\to\infty}\vert a_n\vert=0\text{, }\text{then }\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$

I'm cool with this being true, looks good to me.

So I thought, "what about the converse?"

$\displaystyle\text{If }\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0\text{, }\text{then }\lim_{n\to\infty}\vert a_n\vert=0$

I was told this is false, but I'm having trouble thinking of a counterexample that proves that. Anybody know one?

Comment: You can't find a counterexample because it is true. If $a_n\to0$, then for any $\epsilon>0$ we can find $N$ so $|a_n|<\epsilon$ when $n>N$. Since $\big||a_n|\big|=|a_n|$, that's the same thing as saying $|a_n|\to0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The converese is true, this follows immediatelly from $||a_n|-0|=|a_n-0|$.

In particular, $\lim_n a_n=0 \Leftrightarrow \lim_n|a_n|=0$.

What it was probably told to you is the following:

**Lemma** If $\lim_n a_n=L$ then $\lim_n |a_n|=|L|$.

Note that if $L \neq 0$ the converse of this statement is false, and a counterexample is
$$
a_n=(-1)^n L
$$